# Different results when making a Corda query via API and inside a flow

Tags: blockchain, corda

I’m getting some strange behaviour. When I update a state with a list of partner ids - other nodes - and and read the state afterwards it seems that via `rpcOps.vaultQueryBy` I can see the updated - or unconsumed - state with the updated list of partners, but if I do same query via `serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy` it looks like the state’s parner list hasn’t changed at all.

If I get all states in the flow - also the consumed - it looks like there has not been a change, but via API all updates into partners list are visible. Is this some sort of a bug I have encountered or am I just not understanding something?

We're using Corda 4.0.

Via API

```
var servicestates = rpcOps.vaultQueryBy<ServiceState>().states.map { it.state.data }
var services = getServices().filter {
            it.linearId == UniqueIdentifier.fromString(serviceId)
        }.single()
```

Inside flow

```
val serviceStateAndRef = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<ServiceState>(
                    QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(linearId = listOf(serviceLinearId))
                ).states.single()
```

Comment: Can you check if your `serviceLinearId` is correctly passed in? Are you calling the flow from node shell? or via API?

Comment: Yes, linearId is correct. That's the most worrying thing. Everything else looks completely correct but the missing partners list. Flow is called via API.

Comment: It seems that inside the flow I'm only getting consumed states. If I set the criteria as unconsumed, I get the last consumed - not the unconsumed state.

Comment: I checked the H2 database and states are consumed and created just as thought. But for some reason linearQuery will fail to fetch the unconsumed one.

Comment: Can you try to print the criteria created and see what's the stateStatus inferred. I presume by default it should only get unconsumed. I am surprised how is getting consumed.

Comment: Criteria looks completely normal: LinearStateQueryCriteria(participants=null, uuid=[e1752444-990b-4703-aac7-312cb8c19c22], externalId=[], status=UNCONSUMED, contractStateTypes=[class com.template.state.ServiceState], relevancyStatus=ALL)

Comment: Also when comparing transaction ids, the last consumed state is returned with the status UNCONSUMED, where as in the database it set as consumed - it has CONSUMED_TIMESTAMP set and STATE_STATUS set as 1.

Comment: This is really weird. Are you sure, your client is point to the same party where you are running the flow? I mean in both the cases the client and the flow both are referring the same node.

Comment: The only reason I see this might happen is probably that your client is connected to a different node where the state is consumed and the flow you are referring to is running on a different node where the state is unconsumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ashutosh Meher You got it near enough. The problem was in a previous flow, where, when creating a new partner state the command call for contract, there was only the caller listed.

So

`Command(ServiceContract.Commands.AddPartner(),listOf(ourIdentity.owningKey))`

had to be edited to include necessary other parties.

`Command(ServiceContract.Commands.AddPartner(),updatedServiceState.participants.map { it.owningKey })`

That resulted the other node not to see the change. It was right under my eyes all the time... ;)